# Does Dororo meet Hyakkimaru again in the ending?

Tags: dororo

At the end of the anime, Dororo grows up and becomes a beautiful girl, and she is running to Hyakkimaru, right?

Also, he is standing in a field. Which means, does Dororo and Hyakkimaru meet again?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Hyakkimaru looked a bit older there, too. This could be an argument for why this scene doesn't simply reflect Dororo's wish to be together with him again, but a fact that's actually going to happen since she wouldn't have known his older appearance if she wouldn't have met him.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm no expert, but from what I see, I think they do meet again, however, not in that instance.

Dororo said she'd bring back the money in a few days, the three men didn't seem to be on the bridge but watching Dororo run across it. Hyakkimaru was found at the end, with a smile. I suppose there will be a journey and they meet again at a new age.

The bridge could represent the journey, and the field could represent the gold Dororo is going to get. Hyakkimaru meeting her there. Don't forget the mother of Hyakkimaru stated child who would be by his side forever.

So, if not meeting, then I'm sure they'll meet in the future. Now if it is to be their meeting, then it's foreshadowing that Dororo becomes a woman of course, and all the time she does, she's right there with Hyakkimaru.

Answer (score 1):

I think they might meet somewhere in the future.

As for the bridge, I think it means the journey ahead of them, while discovering their own paths - with Dororo helping the men out using the money and Hyakkimaru finding a path that doesn't involve murder since he has killed so many to regain his body.

The field probably doesn't represent the gold Dororo used, but rather Hyakkimaru's path - in which he helped people with famine, etc. by using the rice seeds Mio took from the samurai and wanted to plant them with the orphans before they were killed, saying that when it was growing it looked like a sea of gold. Meaning that he has found a way to help without killing and also made Mio's dream come true.

Answer (score 1):

I’m sure they did not part. As Biwamaru said, they still have so much greater than what they have experienced TOGETHER ahead of them.

Also, the gold field probably did not only represent Dororo's money but if you remember Mio, the woman whose voice comforted Hyakkimaru, along with the children she fed, she and they wished for their own field, so MAYBE Hyakkimaru and Dororo fulfilled that wish in their absence.

Answer (score 1):

One of my interpretations: the bridge could represent the journey they both take by themselves to improve themselves. And in the end, the other is waiting on the other side of the bridge, which means after the hardship and the journey, they will meet again. A sea of gold represented by the field that the orphans dreamed of that could possibly be a result of them making the dreams come true as a sign of remembrance for the orphans.

Another one is a bit sad: they go on and live their journey, never meeting during their living years, but they go to heaven represented by the field that looked like a sea of gold, and they meet again at the end of the bridge. The reason they're both looking a little grown-up is because that is how they want to be seen.